# is it possible to have a gradient for SSS value

Tags: rendering, node-editor, subsurface-scattering

So I've got a scene with curtain and there's 2 main materials that I use for it, one is with 0 sss basically it's for the part of curtain that's rolled up and second is with 1 sss which is the open curtain which blocks the sun

Now the part where both are separated is totally unrealistic and I want it to gradually change from 0 to 1 sss, It's hard to say but in simpler words a part where the top and bottom part of it would blend

I tried a setup with coloramp as the value for sss color and as sss values but both doesn't work, I'll upload blend file containing the curtain

[image: Image for better understanding]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try scaling the subsurface radius based on the gradient instead, something like this:

[image: SSS along a gradient]

This will let the light pierce deeper through the object on one end of the gradient.

You can move the gradient texture around with a mapping node like this:

[image: Repositioning the gradient]

Or just use whatever method you were using before to create a gradient where you want it, you don't have to use the gradient node.

Comment: wow, I'll try as soon as I get back, I'm using blender for a few months but I had no idea there was a gradient texture, btw what does the scale parameter control ? does it act like a multiply value

Comment: Yes it acts as a multiply value, a vector math node set to multiply would do the same thing here.

Comment: I tried it but I Can't seem to rotate it horizontally